# Read Vault secret with VaultSharp in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, vaultsharp

The VaultSharp package seems to contain all I want and it is well-documented.
 I tried to use VaultSharp package to read our secrets from a Vault server.
 But my rusty C# stopped me at line

```
Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2
     .ReadSecretAsync("/secret/my_corp/my_app/dev/db_creds");
```

with error message:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
> Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing
> its return type to 'Task'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VaultSharp;
using VaultSharp.V1.AuthMethods.AppRole;
using VaultSharp.V1.AuthMethods;
using VaultSharp.V1.Commons;
using VaultSharp.V1.AuthMethods.Token;

namespace VaultConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vaultUrl = "https://vault-server.url.com:443";
            Program.by_token(vaultUrl);
        }
     
        static void by_token(string vaultUrl)
        {
            // Initialize one of the several auth methods.
            IAuthMethodInfo authMethod = new TokenAuthMethodInfo("s.R2gFHDiup5wCeHHksfc2zKUN");

            // Initialize settings. You can also set proxies, custom delegates etc. here.
            var vaultClientSettings = new VaultClientSettings(vaultUrl, authMethod);

            IVaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient(vaultClientSettings);

            // Use client to read a key-value secret.
            Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync("/secret/my_corp/my_app/dev/db_creds");
        }
    }
}
```

The codes are essentially copied from http://rajanadar.github.io/VaultSharp/

Comment: Do what the message tells you to do.

Comment: Microsoft has great documentation about this: [ms async docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/)


 ; Depending on what you're trying to achieve you'll be better off using a library for loading configuration. Check these out:

[stratio.externsions.configuration.vault](https://github.com/stratio-automotive/Stratio.Extensions.Configuration.Vault)
[VaultSharp.Extensions.Configuration](https://github.com/MrZoidberg/VaultSharp.Extensions.Configuration)
[NetEscapades.Configuration.Vault](https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration)

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you exactly what you need to know. Though let's extrapolate:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. **Consider
> marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
> type to 'Task'**.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var vaultUrl = "https://vault-server.url.com:443";
    await Program.by_token(vaultUrl);
}

 
static async Task by_token(string vaultUrl)
{
    ...
    Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync("/secret/my_corp/my_app/dev/db_creds");
}
```

At this time you should do some research on the *async and await* pattern:

- [Stephen Cleary : Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
- [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
- [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I did not write C# for a while and did not use async and await before,

Comment: It runs. But when I tried to see what got returns using: Console.Writeline("data {0}",  kv2Secret.Data);  then the last line was not reached and I could not get the data. Obviously I still do not understand how the await works. How can I get the data returned after the ReadSecretAsync method execution?

Comment: If you cannot use async for whatever reason, you can try this sync way. Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync("/secret/my_corp/my_app/dev/db_creds").Result

Comment: @RajaNadar there is a good chance this will cause a deadlock in a UI framework

Comment: Yes. Agree. The op has a console app. And it looked like they are just trying out the snippet. Hence I didn't call the deadlock aspect with the usage of .Result out. The Vault sharp docs do call out sync usage and deadlock risks. VaultSharp also has a continuationcontext flag to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the method async you can also remove "await" which will make it synchronous and not async.

```
var kv2Secret = vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync("/secret/my_corp/my_app/dev/db_creds");
```

The best thing to do for you depends on your use case though so I suggest reading up on it first as suggested in other answer.